# Determine the number of zeros for $4z^3-12z^2+2z+10$ in $\frac{1}{2}<|z-1|<2$.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I'm faced with the problem in the title

> Determine the number of zeros for $4z^3-12z^2+2z+10$ in the annulus $\frac{1}{2}<|z-1|<2$.

Clearly this requires a nifty application of [Rouche's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rouch%C3%A9%27s_theorem). Why this isn't  so easy for me is because the annulus isn't centered at the origin. In those cases in which it is centered at the origin, it's a simple plugging in of numbers. Could anybody suggest a next step to take?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I just figured out what to do while writing this, so I'm going to write the trick out here for anybody that might run across the same problem I had.

Just write the polynomial $4z^3-12z^2+2z+10$ as a Taylor Polynomial centered at $z=1$. You don't actually need to use Taylor's theorem for this - using algebra could do it also.

Doing that, you get $4(z-1)^3-10(z-1)+4$. With a simple substitution $s=z-1$, we get $4s^3-10s+4$, and from there it's trivial.

Comment: Why is it trivial to find the zeroes of that cubic?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese It's not necessarily trivial to find the zeros of that cubic, but it's trivial to apply Rouché's theorem (twice) to find the number of zeros in the annulus $\frac{1}{2} < \lvert s\rvert < 2$.

Comment: I never said it was trivial to find the zeros of that cubic, but as Daniel Fischer said, it's trivial to apply Rouche's Theorem and find that 2 zeros lie within the annulus $\frac{1}{2}<|s|<2$.